# Запрет переноса слов через дефис

Tags: html, css

Как запретить перенос слов через дефис?
Допустим

```
some text wi-fi
```

если блок узкий, как запретить перенос fi  на другую строку?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61730/discussion-on-question-by-word-----).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Использовать вместо обычного дефиса неразрывный `&#8209;` - при нормальной кодировке (utf8) его можно просто писать как символ в тексте `‑`:

```css
p {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 15ch;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p>wi-fi wi-fi wi-fi wi-fi wi-fi wi-fi wi-fi wi-fi wi-fi wi-fi
<p>wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi wi&#8209;fi
<p>wi‑fi wi‑fi wi‑fi wi‑fi wi‑fi wi‑fi wi‑fi wi‑fi wi‑fi wi‑fi
```